# How to get redirect route from laravel redirectResponse?

Tags: php, laravel

So I'm trying to test my laravel’s middleware which will return redirection.

If the request did not satisfy the middleware’s requirements, the request will be redirect using `redirect()->route('name')`

I tried getting the return value from the middleware like so

```
$response = $middleware->handle($request, function ($req) { return $req; }, 'server:summary:view:edit');
\Log::info($response);
```

the `$response` is instance of `Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse`.
When I do `\Log::info($response);` I get this result.

```
HTTP/1.0 302 Found
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Date:          Mon, 13 Jul 2020 08:12:27 GMT
Location:      https://myrandomurl.test/name

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url='https://myrandomurl.test/name" />

        <title>Redirecting to https://myrandomurl.test/name</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        Redirecting to <a href="https://myrandomurl.test/name">https://myrandomurl.test/named</a>.
    </body>
</html>
```

So how do I get the url from the Location tag ? or How do I get the redirect url from laravel redirectResponse ?

I tried browsing the doc at https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Http/RedirectResponse.html#method_content but there's no method that shows redirect route.

I need the route to assert it for successful test result.

Comment: Location is a header so, how about `$response->header('Location')` ?

Comment: @apokryfos didn't work. `header()` method on `redirectResponse` is used to set the request header. not get.

Comment: Possibly `$response->headers->get('Location')` might work in that case, however if this is a test there are assertions that can do this as well like [`assertRedirect`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/http-tests#assert-redirect)

Comment: @apokryfos Can't use `$response->headers->get('Location')` since `redirectResponse` didn't have `headers` properties. But Oh shit you right about the `assertRedirect()`. I should've used that. I probably should delete this question then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse` inherits `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse` class that has `getTargetUrl` method:

```php
$response->getTargetUrl();
```

Instead you may use [`assertRedirect`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/http-tests#assert-redirect) for testing purposes.